# How does one access subviews and handle groups of them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

1. If I want to manipulate a view I get it with `[self viewWithTag:5];`. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Sometimes I need to manipulate a bunch of view (e.g. move them all out of the way. I do this by adding a UIView (e.g. UIView iHoldViews) and then adding the views, buttons, etc to this view. Then I can move the iHoldViews view and all its subviews move with it. Is there a better way to do this? (I have a feeling there is :) Maybe storing them in a NSArray or NSMutableDictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For views you need frequently, it is recommended to have ivars for them. Wire them up in InterfaceBuilder or in code.
2. Both ways (via a view or a collection) are possible. If they are visually grouped, I'd use a UIView, if they build different units that just happen to be moved together, a collection would make more sense. Non-opaque views have a performance hit, so this might be a consideration if you have evidence that you are too slow.

Comment: Sometimes items in this UIView do not respond to touches properly. eg. I have UITextView in this view and it does not respond to touches like it should. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a different problem. As long as your views are correctly sized and not covered by other views, they should work as expected.